# If $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is an isomorphism, prove that $f$ is the identity map.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I am a little baffled by this question. Is it safe to assume that since $f$ is an isomorphism, $f (1) = 1$ ? And, if it is safe to assume this, could I construct a proof by induction, by using the fact that $f(1) =1$,$f(-1)=-f(1)$, $f(1+1) = f(1) +f(1)$, .... etc. to prove the claim? Thanks for your time as always guys!

Comment: An isomorphism of rings? of groups? of lattices? of sets?

Comment: The word "isomorphism" is ambiguous here.  Do you mean an isomorphism of rings?

Comment: If it is a ring isomorphism, one can prove that $f(1)=1$. It then follows, using the argument that you *sketched*, that $f$ is the identity map.

Comment: Although it doesn't specify in the question, I'm assuming an "isomorphism of rings"

Comment: Well, it's not true in the case of groups: if $f \colon \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is an isomorphism of groups, then $f$ is surjective, so $f(n) = 1$ for some nonzero $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $f(n\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}$ since $1$ generates $\mathbb{Z}$ as a group, but this means $f$ can clearly not be injective unless $n = \pm 1$. Of course, $n = -1$ is a perfectly good choice, and in fact $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z})$ is a group with two elements. In the case of rings, one can show that $n = 1$ is the only choice; of course, some people *define* a ring homomorphism as mapping $1$ to $1$...

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you mean an automorphism in the additive group of the integers. In this case what you are trying to prove is false.

You can prove by induction (first with the case $n\ge 0$ and then use $f(-n)=-f(n)$) that $f(n)=nf(1)$ for all integer $n$. Thus if we want a surjective map we need $nf(1)=1$ for some integers $n$ and $f(1)$ hence $f(1) \in \{-1,+1\}$. It is easy to see that in these two cases we indeed get an isomorphism so it is not unique.